# Unity - Trying to copy the render texture for the scene rendered by a camera but it is blank?

Tags: unity, c#, rendering, rendertargets

I'm trying to copy the scene rendered by a particular camera to a render target.  I know this should be possible to do without using the camera's target texture as I read through [this](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2015/02/06/extending-unity-5-rendering-pipeline-command-buffers/) official Unity article about Command Buffers which avoids any use of them.

Instead, I found that they use the following code in the renderer for blurry refractions (CommandBufferBlurRefraction.cs) to copy the scene to a render target.

```
    buf = new CommandBuffer();
    buf.name = "Grab screen and blur";
    m_Cameras[cam] = buf;

    // copy screen into temporary RT
    int screenCopyID = Shader.PropertyToID("_ScreenCopyTexture");
    buf.GetTemporaryRT(screenCopyID, -1, -1, 0, FilterMode.Bilinear);
    buf.Blit(BuiltinRenderTextureType.CurrentActive, screenCopyID);
```

The problem is that I can't get this to work for myself using a very simple scenario of:

- Camera renders the entire scene which is a single hexagonal sprite
- The command buffer assigned to the camera grabs the BuiltinRenderTextureType.CurrentActive (Scene Render Target)
- The command buffer then copies that to another render target
- That render target is then drawn in the upper left of the screen on a yellow background

This results in the scene render target being completely blank and not including the white hexagon.

[image: CopySceneRTToRenderTargetFail]

The code I am using is

```
Camera cameraUsedToRender;
CommandBuffer commandBuffer;
RenderTexture debugRT;
Texture2D debugRTBackground;

void Awake()
{
    // Create debug texture to render
    debugRTBackground = new Texture2D(2, 2);
    debugRTBackground.SetPixels(new Color[4] { Color.yellow, Color.yellow, Color.yellow, Color.yellow });
    debugRTBackground.Apply();

    cameraUsedToRender = Camera.main;
    cameraUsedToRender.orthographicSize = 10f;

    // Create debug render texture to render to using our camera
    debugRT = new RenderTexture(cameraUsedToRender.pixelWidth, cameraUsedToRender.pixelHeight, 16);
    debugRT.Create();

    // Create command buffer
    commandBuffer = new CommandBuffer();
    commandBuffer.name = "Debug";

    // Add the camera buffer to the main camera
    cameraUsedToRender.AddCommandBuffer(CameraEvent.BeforeImageEffectsOpaque, commandBuffer);
}

void OnRenderObject()
{
    // Clear the command buffer
    commandBuffer.Clear();

    // Set the render target
    commandBuffer.SetRenderTarget(debugRT);

    // Clear the render target
    commandBuffer.ClearRenderTarget(true, true, Color.blue);

    // Copy scene into a render target
    // RenderTarget.active = SceneView RT (UnityEngine.RenderTexture)
    commandBuffer.Blit(BuiltinRenderTextureType.CurrentActive, debugRT);

    // Release the render target
    commandBuffer.SetRenderTarget(null as RenderTexture);
}

void OnGUI()
{
    // Draw the debug render target (which should have the SceneView RT copied to it)
    GUI.DrawTexture(new Rect(0, 0, 130, 130), debugRTBackground);
    GUI.DrawTexture(new Rect(1, 1, 128, 128), debugRT);
}
```

The complete small, simple project that demonstrates this issue can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cgimbtj4ib3twq7/DebugRendering.zip?dl=0).

Does anyone have an idea how to resolve this as I'm finding the Unity rendering pipeline to be rather confusing at this point?

Answer (score 2):

Try to remove all calls in `OnRenderObject` except

```
commandBuffer.Blit(BuiltinRenderTextureType.CurrentActive, debugRT);
```

And I believe you don't have to call that one even every time, because it is a state call, so you only have to call it on initialization (in your `Awake` function. (Maybe don't initialize in `Awake`, but in `Start`?)).

Answer (score 2):

```
// Set the render target
commandBuffer.SetRenderTarget(debugRT);
```

Here you're setting your current render target tl be the debug RenderTexture.

```
// Copy scene into a render target 
// RenderTarget.active = SceneView RT (UnityEngine.RenderTexture) 
commandBuffer.Blit(BuiltinRenderTextureType.CurrentActive, debugRT);
```

Here you're copying from the current render target into the debug RenderTexture.

But wait, the current render target *is* the debug RenderTexture! That's what we set it to just a few lines above. So this call is asking to copy from one buffer into the same buffer, never looking at the scene render target's contents at all.